# SharePoint Apps turned off.

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-apps

I have installed SharePoint 2013, and configured a team site.

I am able to add default app like list and document library. But when I try to add some app from the SharePoint store, I get a message that the apps are turned off and contact your system administrator.

I researched a little in the internet and it said that I have to create a dedicated app domain to avail this feature.

Let me know few insights regard this. Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Sharepoint administration, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great TechNet Article on [Configure an environment for apps for SharePoint (SharePoint 2013)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236(v=office.15).aspx)

Apps rely on the App Management and Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings service applications. These service applications use the multi-tenancy features to provide app permissions and create the sub domains for apps

You'll need to create a Web Application for your Apps to be hosted in and run.

Other than that double check your SSL certificates.

Let us know if have an issue.

Regards,

Vince

Comment: I use share-point only for an intranet team site. Still do I need to get a domain to configure apps or can i use the internal/ default URL to configure apps. If you could share me some more articles with steps in details, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Best link I have found on Apps is: [Install and manage apps for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161232(v=office.15).aspx).
You can skip the DNS step if its internal

Comment: If I skip DNS, then what abt a domain with SSL all? Or is it much simpler that I configure a domain only with http that too a subdomain and follow the steps.